# Ubuntu 14.04 left launcher doesn't show up

Tags: gnome, 14.04

[image] 
I just migrated from 12.04 to 14.04 and I noticed that I can't open this launcher menu if I am not in 'Dash'

Previously (12.04) I could touch left edge of the desktop to trigger this menu to open, but right now it is not possible.

Can someone point me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I simply forgot that I used this extension, which is by the way great extension

[image]

[Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/)